# Using MySQL user-defined variable in stored procedure for 'in' clause

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

When sending a string of comma separated ids, as a varchar, to a MySQL stored procedure I can not use the string as part of an IN clause with the correct results returned. The string is truncated as a decimal and only the first value is being used.

I thought I would be able to get around this by preparing and then executing the statement, but this still only returned a match for the first value.

Code examples may make things a bit clearer. I want to convert the following into a stored procedure (with the in clause dynamic):

```
select id, name from cities where id in (1,2,3);
```

This is my stored procedure using a prepared statement:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cities_select_by_ids` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cities_select_by_ids`(
    in _cityIds varchar(1000)
)
BEGIN
SET  @cityIds = _cityIds;

PREPARE stmt FROM '
    select
      id,
      name
    from cities
    where id in (?);
';

EXECUTE stmt USING @cityIds;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling the stored procedure I only get a match for the city '1':

```
call cities_select_by_ids_prepare('1, 2, 3');
```

Here is a create and insert script for the table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
insert into cities (name) values ('London'), ('Manchester'), ('Bristol'), ('Birmingham'), ('Brighton');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

due to the way parameterization works, this is not possible.

the closest you can get it this:

```
where find_in_set(id, ?)
```

but this will not scale as as can not use an index.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I worried - at least I now know though.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cities_select_by_ids_2`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `cities_select_by_ids_2`(
    in cityIDs varchar(1000)
)

BEGIN

#- ix - index into the list of city IDs
# cid - city ID
SET @ix := 1;
SET @cid := substring_index(cityIDs, ',', @ix);

LOOP_1: 
WHILE (@cid is not null) DO
    SELECT id,  name 
    FROM cities
        WHERE id in (@cid) ;

     #-- substring_index returns complete cityIDs string when index is > number of elements
     IF (length(substring_index(cityIDs, ',', @ix)) >= length(cityIDs)) THEN
          LEAVE LOOP_1;
     END IF;

     SET @ix := @ix + 1;
     SET @cid = substring_index(substring_index(cityIDs, ',', @ix), ',', -1);

END WHILE;
END 

#----
call cities_select_by_ids_2('1, 2');
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative.

Query below only works for supported PREPARED statements inside stored procedures. MySQL 5.0 I think. Which is alot better than using "find_in_set". Use double quotes "" for string.

```
/* Check your mysql version */

BEGIN
SET @sql_text:=concat(
   'SELECT 
      id,
      name
    FROM db.table
    WHERE 
      id IN 
      (',

      /* BEGIN Parameter */
      '91,57',
      /* END Parameter */

      ') ORDER BY id ASC');

PREPARE stmt from @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: This is good, but FYI, you are missing a closing parenthesis just before ORDER.